# Tips on putting spacing between cells

Tags: ios, swift, loops, cells, spacing

How do i add spacing between each cell here -

```
    for i in 0...50 {
        let cell = UIView()
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: Double(i) * Double(32.52), y: 90, width: 350, height: 500)
        view.addSubview(cell)
    }
```

Because with the code above the view looks like this

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like your code is just laying a bunch of views on top of each other. Maybe you should set your view width to 32.52 and the x position to `Double(i) * Double(32.52) + i*3` to give a 3 point space between your cells.

Answer (score 0):

Your cells are much too wide for the increment you're using horizontally.  Your increment offsets them by 32.52 (why the fractional part?) and the views have a width of 350.

So your view spans will be:

```
From X  up to 
------  -----
0       350
32.52   403.52  (overlapping from 32.53 to 350)
65.04   456.04  (overlapping from 65.04 to 403.52)
and so on ...
```

You probably meant to use a narrower frame width (or a larger increment).

The spacing will be the difference between your increment and the frame width.

For example:  an increment of 32 with a width of 30 will give you a 2 pixel gap between views.

Comment: I was trying to have the app look like tinder, i wanted the cell to have the image of a user with name and the age inside of it. I was trying to do that but i'm still new to swift. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: You should look into UITableView for this.